# for loop wont increment by one on game javascript rock, paper, scissors

Tags: javascript

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game and I can't seem to get the for loop to increment by one after the conditions are true. For example, if the player wins a round, then the `playerWins` should go up by 1 and vice versa. I could only get it to become one but once the player loses a round the `playerWins` or `computerWins` returns back to 0.

```js
const arry = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

let playerWins = 0;
let computerWins = 0;

let computerChoice = () => {
    return arry[Math.floor(Math.random()* 3)]
};


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    
        if ( playerSelection == arry[0] && computerSelection == arry[2] || 
            playerSelection == arry[1] && computerSelection == arry[0] || 
            playerSelection == arry[2] && computerSelection == arry[1]) {
             
            return playerWins + i; 
        
        } else if (computerSelection == arry[0] && playerSelection == arry[2] || 
            computerSelection == arry[1] &&playerSelection == arry[0] || 
            computerSelection == arry[2] && playerSelection == arry[1]) {
             
            return computerWins += i;
        
        } else {
            
            return 'tie'
        
        }
    }
};
    
const computerSelection = computerChoice();

const playerSelection = 'paper';

console.log(playerSelection, computerSelection)
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
console.log(playerWins, computerWins)
```

Comment: You're returning from the function on the first iteration (in three possible ways).

Comment: `playerWins + i;` does not modify the `playerWins` variable.

Comment: Why is there a `for` loop here in the first place? It should only implement playing one round, not all 3 at once. The winner should have their wins incremented by 1, not 0 or 2 (the other possible values for `i`).